# Tkinter - Update button names, from txt file

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have been reading and googling for a few hours and I'm lost.
My problem is, that I am writing a small script, and it has buttons created from a txt file like this:

```
mylist = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r')as file:
    mylist = file.read().splitlines()
for item in mylist:
    button = Button(master, text=item, command=functools.partial(func, item))
    button.pack()
```

However I also have a part of my code, that writes new names to my sample.txt.
Now I can't figurer out how to add a button that upon pressing will refresh/reload mylist and add the new buttons.

I'm guessing that I need to define a function, and then bind that to a button like this:

```
def refresh()
    I don't know :/

refresh_button = Button(master, text="Refresh", command=refresh)
btn.pack
```

But I can't figurer out, what my function should contain (I have dabbled with destroying my entire master window and reloading the entire script, but It wouldn't work, and it also seems unnecessary)

Any ideas for a def refresh?

Comment: Question: will there always be the same number of names/buttons? Or on `refresh` can the number of buttons change? This changes whether or not you decide to destroy all buttons then create a new bunch, or just update the text in the existing buttons.

Comment: The reason to update would be because one had written one or more lines too the sample file, thus there will always be more buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updating the text and command using `configure()`

If the number of buttons will remain the same, then you can create the buttons once, and just update the text inside each one.

```py
# its good practise to not import all (aka dont "from tkinter import *")
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# the number of buttons is fixed
numberOfButtons = 5
# a list for storing all of the buttons so we can configure them later
buttonList = []

# create all the buttons and add them to the list
for i in range(numberOfButtons):
    button = Button(root)
    button.pack()
    buttonList.append(button)

# this reads the file names, and updates the buttons in the list to use those names
def refresh():
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
        # read the list of names and limit the size to numberOfButtons
        nameList = file.read().splitlines()[:numberOfButtons]
        # enumerate lets use have the index and name in one go
        for index, name in enumerate(nameList):
            buttonList[index].configure(text=name, command=functools.partial(func, name))

# button to update named buttons
refreshButton = tk.Button(root, text='refresh', command=refresh)
refreshButton.pack()

# call once to initially give the buttons a value
refresh()

root.mainloop()
```

#### Destroying and recreating buttons each time

But if the number of buttons changes, then you're probably better of destroying all of the buttons and creating them anew every time you update the names.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# list of buttons so we can remove them
buttonList = []

def refresh():
    # destroy all existing buttons
    for i in range(len(buttonList)):
        button = buttonList.pop()
        button.destroy()
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
        nameList = file.read().splitlines()
        # create new buttons for each name in the list
        for name in nameList:
            button = tk.Button(root, text=name, command=functools.partial(func, name))
            buttonList.append(button)
            button.pack()

# button to update named buttons
refreshButton = tk.Button(root, text='refresh', command=refresh)
refreshButton.pack()

# call to initially create the buttons
refresh()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code for destroying and recreating buttons each time really did the trick, thanks a lot!
However, pycharm says that I should replace the 'i' from  "for i in range(len(buttonList)):" with a 'underscore' so it would be "for _ in range(len(mylist)):". I googled it and isn't 'underscore' more correct for a dummy variable holder then 'i'?

Comment: At the end of the day it doesn't *really* matter, but yeah I suppose it wouldn't do any harm. Its mostly a preference thing, but the reason that you might use `_` is because `i` isn't used inside the loop at all, so there's no need for it to be legible, and `_` is pretty invisible on its own so the code becomes easier to scan read with cluttered surroundings. Gotta love pycharm!

Comment: One thing though, is that you mentioned that there will only ever be *more* names added, so its possible to combine the two codes to only create *new* buttons rather than deleting them all. But the one I wrote is safer in general.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Yeah pycharm is pretty great, even for beginners because it's helps you with syntax, and other stuff. I prefer destroying them all, because this gives me the opportunity to remove buttons later on.